# Turn two digit code of country that API returns to show a flag image that I have saved as a .png file

Tags: ios, swift, api

I am calling an API that returns eSport data--the API does not return images; however, it does return a two digit country code (i.e. "US"- for United States) I have all country flags in a file as .png files.

Is there a way to connect the country code that the API returns to the png file and show the png file on my view controller with an image view?

MY CODE:

```
class MatchViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var Match: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var MatchDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Match2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var matchImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var match2Image: UIImageView!



    var match: Match?

    func setupCell(match: Match){
        self.match = match
        let matchDate = match.date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: matchDate) {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy, hh:mm a zzz"
            gregorian.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
            MatchDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

        }else{
            MatchDate.isHidden = true
        }
        //Match.text =  "\(getParticipant1()) VS. \(getParticipant2())"
        Match.text =  "\(getParticipant1()) VS."
        Match2.text =  "\(getParticipant2())"
        Match.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    }

    func getParticipant1() -> String {
        if match?.opponents[0].participants.name != "" {
            return (self.match?.opponents[0].participants.name)!
        } else {
            return "TBD"
        }
    }

    func getParticipant2() -> String {
        if match?.opponents[1].participants.name != "" {
            return (self.match?.opponents[1].participants.name)!
        } else {
            return "TBD"
        }
    }
    func getParticipant1Country() -> String{
        if match?.opponents[0].participants.country != ""{
            return (self.match?.opponents[0].participants.country)!
        }else{
            return "TBD"
        }

}
    func getParticipant2Country() -> String{
        if match?.opponents[1].participants.country != ""{
            return (self.match?.opponents[1].participants.country)!
        }else{
            return "TBD"
        }

}

}
```

Comment: If it's for iOS, have you tried using `UIImageView.image = UIImage(named: \(yourCode).png)` ?

Comment: It is for iOS      I can hardcode the image in with the above; however, what I am trying to do is use the country that is returned from the api and then have it reference the corresponding image to fill the imageview

Comment: iOS means some differences due to the lack of an overt file system. Juan gave you some good code. Without **your** code, along with a better description of where things stand (build errors, runtime behavior, and again, code on your end) it's pretty hard to debug.

Comment: OK.  So, I edited my question to include my code.  I have the country 2 digit code returning from the api within a label on my story board--however, I am trying to show a flag of the country next to that label in an imageview. I have the .png images saved in my project under a group file name FlagImages